# Tk's clipboard command sometimes not setting system clipboard

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I've noticed that Tk's clipboard command sometimes does not really append to the system clipboard. I've noticed this in other programs previously (tkcon for example) where if I copy some text and try to paste it into another program (notepad for example) I get nothing. Sometimes I need to do the copy again in order to get the text into the clipboard.

I'm currently developing my own text editor ([see pure console text editor 2](http://wiki.tcl.tk/16056%E2%80%8E) on the tcler's wiki or on [github](https://github.com/slebetman/tcled)) and I can't get the clipboard to work accross applications.

The implementation looks simple enough:

```
clipboard clear
clipboard append -- [join $copy_lines \n]
```

but it doesn't work. By doesn't work I mean it works within the running application but if I have two applications open and try to copy from the first and paste into the second then it doesn't work.

Not sure what else I need to do. From the documentation it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem (at least for my program). My program runs in plain old tclsh, not wish and waits for inputs in a busy loop (peppered with `after` commands so as to reduce CPU usage). As such, it never enters the event loop. Turns out Tk updates the clipboard in the event loop (presumably on idle) so the system clipboard never gets updated (though the internal data structures stores the copied text just fine).

The solution is to enter the event loop. Ideally I'd refactor my code to use fileevents instead of a `while` loop. For a quick fix I'm just calling `update` whenever I process user inputs.

As for Tk in general, it appears that copied text dies with the application. So the copied text is available while the program is running but disappears when the program quits. It doesn't seem to happen on my Ubuntu machine. I guess I've got a daemon running that maintains the clipboard. That's OK. I can live with it for now.

Comment: The clipboard (and the other selections) are deeply connected to event handling. Tk doesn't expose the events in question to scripts directly (they get the `selection` and `clipboard` commands) but those are real events as they have to come from the outside world.